# Retargeting to windows 8.1 Error

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

**I want to create XAP/APPX File which run on windows phone and I have a developer account. My current application developed in 8.0 but**

1. Windows phone 8.0  does not have option for

   (i) Store - > Create app package (Which is available in 8.1)
2. With the ‘Re-targeted to windows 8.1 ‘ option it crate ‘windows phone silverlight 8.1’ 
   After clicking store option it show error for "**In Order to run windows app certification kit, your project build configuration must be release and the platform must be ARM or Neutral**" , as per error we change in project but still it show same error

[image]

- what i want to do is, I want to create xap/Appx file which will run on locked device as well. By clicking on Store -> install from local/ sd card.
- Please suggest me proper way to build an xap/appx file, any signing certificate is needed then please let me know.

Comment: Same issue here... Did you resolve it?